# Toggle Accordion functionality with reactstrap?

Tags: reactjs, accordion, infinite-loop, reactstrap

Using the reactstrap documentation, I created a pseudo-accordion with collapsible cards. I want to be able to toggle the cards, so that when I click on the card header of **list 2** once it will open, and it will close again if I click it consecutively. If I click **list 1**, **list 2** should close and **list 1** should open, as expected.

**Accordion Component**:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { Collapse, CardBody, Card, CardHeader } from 'reactstrap';

const Lists = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState('');
    const [lists, setLists] = useState([
        {
            _id: 'id_abc',
            item_names: ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'],
            list_name: 'List 2',
            author_name: 'Samantha Samson',
        },
        {
            _id: 'id_xyz',
            item_names: ['item 1', 'item 1', 'item 2', 'item 16'],
            list_name: 'List 1',
            author_name: 'John Johnson',
        },
    ]);

return (
    <Fragment>
        {lists.map((list) => (
            <Card key={list._id}>
                <CardHeader onClick={() => setIsOpen(list._id)}>
                    <h4>{list.list_name}</h4>
                </CardHeader>
                <Collapse isOpen={isOpen === list._id ? true : false}>
                    <CardBody>
                        <ul>
                            {list.item_names.map((item) => (
                                <li>{item}</li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </CardBody>
                </Collapse>
            </Card>
        ))}
    </Fragment>

);
```

I tried adding a function to the onClick that looked like this:

```
const handleToggle = (id) => {
    if(isOpen === id) {
        setIsOpen('');
    } else {
        setIsOpen(id);
    }
}
```

and gave the header:

```
onClick={handleToggle(list._id)}
```

but that gave many a too many rerenders/infinite loop error.

I also tried slight variations of that function with the same result.

Comment: Rewrite your `onClick` handler like this: `onClick={() => handleToggle(list._id)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pretty much fixed it with this one:

```
  const handleToggle = (id) => {
    if (isOpen === id) {
      setIsOpen("");
    } else {
      setIsOpen(id);
    }
  };
```

So great job! Where you made a mistake is calling it like so:

```
onClick={handleToggle(list._id)}
```

This will call the function on every render and since it updates a state variable, you will get infinite renders.

It should be:

```
onClick={() => handleToggle(list._id)}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-jepsen-1ip0x?file=/src/App.js

**Just FYI:**
You can simplify your ternary operator as:

```
isOpen={isOpen === list._id}
```